# What does this relation signify?

Tags: mathematical-physics

I recently came across this in social media-

[image]

What doe the last equation mean?Is it somehow connected to probability or something?

Thanks a lot for any help or response!!

Comment: It doesn't mean much! It is a parody from quantum mechanics which suggests that the glass is in a mixture of the full and empty states. The $\sqrt{2}$ is a nice touch...

Comment: good observation @tatan

Comment: @dp1611 Welcome back after a long time...

Comment: actually not so.i had been active after the boards...@tatan

Comment: @dp1611 O... but you don't seem to have much recent activities here...

Comment: Got something from the answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a quantum mechanical view ($\psi$ being the wavefunction) of the glass being both empty and half full simultaneously. The $1/\sqrt2$ being included as some kind of "normalisation" of the wavefunction. This is, in real examples, the link with probability where the normalisation ensures the integral of $|\psi|^2$ over all space is $1$.

Here is another relatively famous superposition of states, the Schrodinger's [cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat) thought experiment/paradox where the cat is in a state of being alive and dead simultaneously.